# Disk Quota exceeded, but have 2.0T of available space in /afs directory

Tags: git, ubuntu, diskspace

I'm trying to clone and checkout a few git repos via a brew install command, but I keep getting a Disk Quota exceeded error. This is what I get when I run df -h :

```
Filesystem                                Size  Used Avail Use% 
Mounted on
udev                                      7.8G  4.0K  7.8G   1% /dev
tmpfs                                     1.6G  1.5M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/dm-0                                  25G  6.6G   17G  29% /
none                                      4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                                     7.8G   66M  7.7G   1% /tmp
none                                      5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                                      7.8G   68M  7.7G   1% /run/shm
none                                      100M   68K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_usr_vice_cache        1.5G  1.1G  344M  76% /usr/vice/cache
/dev/sda1                                 464M   42M  399M  10% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_local_mnt             872G  364G  464G  44% /local/mnt
/dev/mapper/vg00-varvol                   4.0G  2.2G  1.6G  59% /var
AFS                                       2.0T     0  2.0T   0% /afs
10.23.102.23:/usr2/fortress_0018/dlenart  170G  105G   66G  62% /usr2/dlenart
```

This is the error I got when I tried to run brew install:

```
Cloning into '/usr2/dlenart/.cache/Homebrew/buildkernel--git'...
remote: Counting objects: 883, done.
remote: Total 883 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 883
Receiving objects: 100% (883/883), 163.57 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (432/432), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
fatal: cannot create directory at 'doc': Disk quota exceeded
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed
```

So I guess my cache is filling up, which makes sense because it is already at 76% capacity. However, I have 2T in the /afs directory! Is there anyway I can use this?

Comment: A disk *quota* is set by some administrator: "We, at the university, have 2 TB of space. You, a lowly student, may only use three bytes." :-) You will need to petition whoever controls this to dole out more space to you, or find some other place to store your files.

Comment: Yep, it would appear to be a quota on `/usr2/dlenart` and nothing to do with `/usr/vice/cache`.

Comment: nuts. Ok thanks :'(

Comment: @Ryan Can I use quotaoff? Well I mean, I did try it. quotaoff -u /usr2/dlenart but it returns: quotaoff: Mountpoint (or device) /usr2/dlenart not found or has no quota enabled. What do you think of this?

Comment: @windfallisland: quotaon / quotaoff at this point are probably mostly just historical artifacts, but even if not, they're what the admin might use and not something you could change. In this case your space is on AFS, which I suspect is the Andrew File System, which is networked and controlled by the guys at the other end of the network wire. See, e.g., https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~help/afs/volumes_quotas.html